# Python Pattern Matching with optional variables

Tags: python, python-3.x, pattern-matching, mypy

I'm using mypy and I have two classes:

```
class Student:
    first_name: str
    ...

class City:
    id: int
    name: str
    ...
```

I have some db function that fetch the data and I end up with these two variables:

```
student: Optional[Student] = ...
city: Optional[City] = ...
```

I want to do pattern match for each case of None or non-None data of both variables.

I want to do different things for each case, this way:

```
match student, city:
    case None, None:
        output = "they all none"
    case Student(), City():
        output = f"student: {student.first_name} lives in {city.name}"
    case _, _:
        output = "one of them is none..."
```

But mypy doesn't recognize student and city as non-None in the second case. I don't want to use `# type: ignore`

Comment: Python will match None, None if these are really the values of student and city. You should print the values before the match and make sure that these are the actual values.

Answer (score -2):

EDITED to consider user19077881 suggestion.
I would go with the classic ifs:

```
if student==None and city==None:
    output = "they all none"
elif student==None or city==None:
    output = "one of them is none..."
else:
    output = f"student: {student.first_name} lives in {city.name}"
```

Comment: That's indeed my plan b, though I was expecting to use pattern matching as it seems to be a really good chance to use it here.